# Slow API calls after turning off sslV3 on server

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, iis-7, coldfusion-10, sslv3

First, I'm way over my head as I know just about nothing about managing a server, even less a server's security settings (I have been externally hosted for 20 years!).

My shared environment host (Newtek) has recently turned off sslV3, (I understand is a good thing -see poodle bug), but since then, some API calls that are being made are slow and some are not.
All API calls to UPS, CanadaPost and Paypal are slow (average of 20 sec per call ) while all calls to FB or Google map are fast (1 sec. per call).
All API calls use HTTPS.

My question to you is either:
-Does anybody have some clues has to what is going on?  And if not, does anybody have any suggestions as to how to find out what is going on? Basically where and how to even look for the source of trouble!?! (As I don't know enough about what is going on behind the scene for any part of these connections to troubleshoot.)

A few notes:

1. After my host investigated various things, they have ruled out xmlParser as the cause,since the slowness can be observed even on dumping the `cfhttp.filecontent`.
2. My host installed a new version of my domain ssl which now uses SHA256.
3. My host server is running CF10 on IIS 7
4. I can't reproduce this on my local development server and of course don't have full access to the live server.
5. There is no CF error to report. Only very slow connection.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Update on situation: Host says they did not change anything but the slowness as disappeared in the last 24 hours.  I can't confirm this but it is possible that for some reason, at first (when sslV3 was deactivated), the server was falling back to TLS 1.0 (that is what I think I was seeing), but now, for sure it is using TLS 1.2.

Comment: Are you using CF Standard?

Comment: Also, are you running JDK 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: If you are referring to cf standard vs cf entreprise... this is a shared hosting environment, so definitely cf Enterprise.
As for JDK, I don't know what they run, but Newtek is very quick to implement any security measures. So I'm pretty sure they would keep update anything related to java.

Comment: you may ask them to update the JDK as it's not something common people do for CF